# Error: Cannot find module when starting NodeJS server via python subprocess call

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, module

I have this script in my `setup.py` file:

```
status = subprocess.check_output(["node", "/setupLocalAPI/app.js"])
print(status)
```

That should call the node server and output it's output (which would be the fact the server has started),
yet whenever I call it I get the error of:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'c:\setupLocalAPI\app.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: []
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Nathan\Dropbox\Projects\projectname\projectnamesourcecode\startup.py", line 20, in <module>
setup.init()
File "c:\Users\Nathan\Dropbox\Projects\projectname\projectnamesourcecode\setup\setup.py", line 31, in init
status = subprocess.check_output(["node", "/setupLocalAPI/app.js"])
File "C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['node', '/setupLocalAPI/app.js']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My project layout is as follows:

```
setup
    setup.py
    __init__.py
    setupLocalAPI
        app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative path `./setupLocalAPI/app.js`